# pgfplots very small Y values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I need to plot the following function: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%281%2Bx%2F5%29+-+%280.997475+%2B0.1+x-0.00499923+x%5E2%2B0.000499811+x%5E3-0.0000645293+x%5E4%2B9.12394x10%5E-6+x%5E5%29+in+%5B-1%2C1%5D

When I pick certain function values for the Y dimensions I got the known dimension too large error:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]

    \begin{axis}[
        height=\textwidth,
        width=\textwidth,
        xmin=-1.05,xmax=1.05,
        %ymin=0.002524,ymax=0.002525,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis line style=<->,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xtick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5, 1},
        scaled y ticks = false,
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci},
        ]


        \addplot[no marks,blue,line width=1pt] expression[domain=-1:1,samples=200]{sqrt(1+x/5) - (0.997475+0.1 * x-0.00499923 *x^2+0.000499811 * x^3-0.0000645293 * x^4+9.12394*10^-6 * x^5)}
            ;


    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I don't understand why I'm receiving a dimension too large error on this interval y = [-1,1]...

When I change the interval to y = [0.002524, 0.002525], I've got an output on the wrong interval:

[image: y = [0.002524, 0.002525]]

Anyone who can point me in the right direction to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PGF math engine is just not precise enough for these kinds of ranges. If you use `gnuplot` to do the calculations instead (by replacing `expression` by `gnuplot` in your code), you get the correct output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]

    \begin{axis}[
        height=\textwidth,
        width=\textwidth,
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style=<->,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        xtick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5, 1},
        scaled y ticks = false,
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=8},
        ]


        \addplot[no marks,blue,line width=1pt] gnuplot [domain=-1:1,samples=200]{sqrt(1+x/5) - (0.997475+0.1 * x-0.00499923 *x^2+0.000499811 * x^3-0.0000645293 * x^4+9.12394*10^-6 * x^5)}
            ;


    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer! But... When I change the `expression` into `gnuplot` I get `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'orthogonale_basisfunc
ties.pgf-plot.table' could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-esc
ape feature? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also in
voke '>> gnuplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file..`

Comment: @MathiasB: Do you have `gnuplot` installed on your system? Do you enable shell escape when compiling your `.tex` file (like the error message says, using `pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>`)?

Comment: My badd, I was convinced that I had `gnuplot` installed, but apparently not on my laptop. (And of course I have problems with my ports collection right know). Thanks for the answers, I'll report as fast as I get my gnuplot installed...

Comment: @MathiasB: No worries! Good luck `=)`