# Plotting a function with very small values in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, pgfmath

I want to plot a function in TikZ, G4 of [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3553717) (p5). I tried with and without pgfplots, and also by gnuplot call. MWE are below.

With `pgfplots`, compilation throws the error `! Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgf@yy l.54 \end{axis}`
whereas the TikZ-only attempt plots instead f(x) = 0.

The function should look like this
[image: Behler function]

This function involves the exponential of a small number multiplied by other small numbers. I suspect that raising the precision of the calculation is enough to fix this. I've seen some examples with `precision=<number>` but I don't know how to do that for a plotted function and not a number to be printed.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213014/213345) shows a gnuplot call for a plot with a very small y-scale, but I'd like to not depend on external programs. Plus I don't know if my macro-reliant definition of the function is compatible with gnuplot. For now I tried changing the macros for explicit numbers, but got an error again, `! Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgf@yy l.43 \end{axis}`

Is there a solution for this? I'm out of my depth.

MWE (TikZ only):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{colorline1}{red}

\def\xmax{360}
\def\ymax{0.02}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={x = 0.025cm,y = 60cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,\ymax) node [left] {\small $G_i^{4,5}$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (\xmax,0) node [below] {\small $\theta_{ijk}$/\si{\degree}};

\node[left] at (0,0) {\small $0$};

\def\coefValT{0.8}

% Cutoff function fc of Rij and Rik, with both distances fixed at 0.8*Rc
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fcOfijNikValT}{0.5*cos( \coefValT * pi r) + 0.5}

\def\lambdaVal{1}
\def\etaVal{0.2}
\def\zetaVal{1}

\def\Rc{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RijNikValT}{\coefValT*\Rc}

% Function to plot begins here
\begin{scope}[thick,colorline1]
\def\fcOfijNik{\fcOfijNikValT}
\draw[domain=0:\xmax,variable=\x,samples=100,smooth] plot (\x,{2^(1-\zetaVal)*(1 + \lambdaVal*cos(\x))^\zetaVal*exp( -\etaVal*( 2*(\RijNikValT)^2 +
% Calculation for Rjk^2:
2*(\RijNikValT)^2 - 2*(\RijNikValT)^2*cos(\x)
))* % these two parenthesis close the one opened by \etaVal*, and by exp(
\fcOfijNik^2*(
% Calculation for fc(Rjk)
0.5*(cos( pi*
% Calculation for Rjk:
(%opens quotient multiplied by pi
sqrt( 2*(\RijNikValT)^2 - 2*(\RijNikValT)^2*cos(\x) )
/\Rc)%ends quotient multiplied by pi
)% closes parenth opened by cos
)% closes parenth opened to the left of cos
+0.5)%closes parenth opened before of 0.5*(cos
});
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

MWE (TikZ+pgfplots):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{colorline1}{red}

\def\xmax{360}
\def\ymax{0.02}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={x = 0.025cm,y = 60cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,\ymax) node [left] {\small $G_i^{4,5}$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (\xmax,0) node [below] {\small $\theta_{ijk}$/\si{\degree}};

\node[left] at (0,0) {\small $0$};

\def\coefValT{0.8}

% Cutoff function fc of Rij and Rik, with both distances fixed at 0.8*Rc
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fcOfijNikValT}{0.5*cos( \coefValT * pi r) + 0.5}

\def\lambdaVal{1}
\def\etaVal{0.2}
\def\zetaVal{1}

\def\Rc{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RijNikValT}{\coefValT*\Rc}

%\begin{axis}[range=0:360,restrict y to domain=0:0.02]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax = 360,ymin = 0, ymax = 0.02]
% Function to plot begins here
\begin{scope}[thick,colorline1]
\def\fcOfijNik{\fcOfijNikValT}
\addplot {2^(1-\zetaVal)*(1 + \lambdaVal*cos(\x))^\zetaVal*exp( -\etaVal*( 2*(\RijNikValT)^2 +
% Calculation for Rjk^2:
2*(\RijNikValT)^2 - 2*(\RijNikValT)^2*cos(\x)
))* % these two parenthesis close the one opened by \etaVal*, and by exp(
\fcOfijNik^2*(
% Calculation for fc(Rjk)
0.5*(cos( pi*(
% Calculation for Rjk:
sqrt( 2*(\RijNikValT)^2 - 2*(\RijNikValT)^2*cos(\x) )
/\Rc)%ends quotient multiplied by pi
)% closes parenth opened by cos
)% closes parenth opened to the left of cos
+0.5)%closes parenth opened before of 0.5*(cos
};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

MWE (TikZ+pgfplots+gnuplot):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{colorline1}{red}

\def\xmax{360}
\def\ymax{0.02}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={x = 0.025cm,y = 60cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,\ymax) node [left] {\small $G_i^{4,5}$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (\xmax,0) node [below] {\small $\theta_{ijk}$/\si{\degree}};

\node[left] at (0,0) {\small $0$};

%\begin{axis}[range=0:360,restrict y to domain=0:0.02]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax = 360,ymin = 0, ymax = 0.02]
% Function to plot begins here
\begin{scope}[thick,colorline1]
\def\fcOfijNik{\fcOfijNikValT}

\addplot[no marks,blue,line width=1pt] gnuplot [domain=0:360,samples=200] {2^(1-1)*(1 + 1*cos(x))^1.1*exp( -0.2*( 2*(8)^2 +
% Calculation for Rjk^2:
2*(8)^2 - 2*(8)^2*cos(x)
))* % these two parenthesis close the one opened by \etaVal*, and by exp(
8^2*(
% Calculation for fc(Rjk)
0.5*(cos( pi*(
% Calculation for Rjk:
sqrt( 2*(8)^2 - 2*(8)^2*cos(x) )
/10)%ends quotient multiplied by pi
)% closes parenth opened by cos
)% closes parenth opened to the left of cos
+0.5)%closes parenth opened before of 0.5*(cos
};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You do not need to know any PGFplots to use it. PGFplots is on top of TikZ. Do youself a favour and look at an example. Slap your plot in between `\begin{axis}` and `\end{axis}` - that is it. Now different googleable options will let you get everything you desire - women, money, ...

Comment: @hpekristiansen Thanks. I've revised the question with the two approaches. Neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to confirm [hpekristiansen's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8650/hpekristiansen): `pgfplots` does work. However, first of all you need to do away with

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style={x = 0.025cm,y = 60cm}}
```

and also with

```
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,\ymax) node [left] {\small $G_i^{4,5}$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (\xmax,0) node [below] {\small $\theta_{ijk}$/\si{\degree}};
```

which become the `ylabel` and `xlabel`, respectively. After this, your code works.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{colorline1}{red}

\def\xmax{360}
\def\ymax{0.02}

%\tikzset{every picture/.style={x = 0.025cm,y = 60cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,\ymax) node [left] {\small $G_i^{4,5}$};
% \draw[->] (0,0) -- (\xmax,0) node [below] {\small $\theta_{ijk}$/\si{\degree}};
% 
% \node[left] at (0,0) {\small $0$};

\def\coefValT{0.8}

% Cutoff function fc of Rij and Rik, with both distances fixed at 0.8*Rc
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fcOfijNikValT}{0.5*cos( \coefValT * pi r) + 0.5}

\def\lambdaVal{1}
\def\etaVal{0.2}
\def\zetaVal{1}

\def\Rc{10}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RijNikValT}{\coefValT*\Rc}

%\begin{axis}[range=0:360,restrict y to domain=0:0.02]
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax = 360,ymin = 0,
    ylabel={\small $G_i^{4,5}$},xlabel={\small $\theta_{ijk}$/\si{\degree}}]
% Function to plot begins here
\begin{scope}[thick,colorline1]
\def\fcOfijNik{\fcOfijNikValT}
\addplot[domain=0:360,samples=201] 
{2^(1-\zetaVal)*(1 + \lambdaVal*cos(\x))^\zetaVal*exp( -\etaVal*( 2*(\RijNikValT)^2 +
% Calculation for Rjk^2:
2*(\RijNikValT)^2 - 2*(\RijNikValT)^2*cos(\x)
))* % these two parenthesis close the one opened by \etaVal*, and by exp(
\fcOfijNik^2*(
% Calculation for fc(Rjk)
0.5*(cos( pi*(
% Calculation for Rjk:
sqrt( 2*(\RijNikValT)^2 - 2*(\RijNikValT)^2*cos(\x) )
/\Rc)%ends quotient multiplied by pi
)% closes parenth opened by cos
)% closes parenth opened to the left of cos
+0.5)%closes parenth opened before of 0.5*(cos
};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is still a very rusty code, and the normalization is different from what you expect, but this is just to substantiate that it works in principle.

If you want a cleaner code then you probably first want to rephrase the question such that others have a better feeling for what's going on.

Comment: It works! My only question left is whether the code could be made clearer. For example, in the myriad of parenthesis. `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` could be used to define the function elsewhere, but that still leaves the myriad of parenthesis. My best idea was to comment the purpose of each. Adding `[`or `{` caused errors.

Comment: @Imp54 You can use the `declare function` key, e.g. `declare function={f(\x,\y)=\x*\x*cos(\y);a0=7;}`, i.e. it works for functions and also for constants like `a0`. You have to be a bit careful to declare functions only locally, e.g. in a `tikzpicture`, because redeclaring them is more efforts.

Comment: So is breaking down the function into smaller functions whenever possible is the best that can be done for this?

Comment: @Imp54 For readability, probably yes. For speed: not sure. What I want to say is that if you define constants with `declare function={a0=7;}` this is arguably much more readable but it may take slightly longer to compile. Yet in 2D plots this should hardly matter.